# Web Color List in C# application

Tags: c#, colors

Hallo everbody,

if for example I set the BackColor of a Panel in Winform using Visual Studio, I can pick up the color from 3 lists:

Custom, Web, System

Is it possible to retreive only the Web colors in my C# code application? They are part of KnownColor but so far I could only find how to eliminate System Control from my list.

I would like to use the web colors because they are sorted in a nice way and I would like to insert them into a self-implemented combobox.

Thank you

Comment: You want to a List<Color> of the KnownColor enum?

Comment: Basically yes but I would like the colors to be sorted like in the Web tab in visual studio.

I tried to sort the colors with some algorithms but the result is not as good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Color` struct contains all the web colors as constants (system colors are defined as constants in `SystemColors` class)

To get a list of these colors just do:

```
var webColors = GetConstants(typeof(Color));
var sysColors = GetConstants(typeof(SystemColors));
```

having `GetConstants` defined as follow:

```
static List<Color> GetConstants(Type enumType)
{
    MethodAttributes attributes = MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = enumType.GetProperties();
    List<Color> list = new List<Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo info = properties[i];
        if (info.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
        {
            MethodInfo getMethod = info.GetGetMethod();
            if ((getMethod != null) && ((getMethod.Attributes & attributes) == attributes))
            {
                object[] index = null;
                list.Add((Color)info.GetValue(null, index));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get colors sorted exactly like in VS do:

```
var webColors = GetConstants(typeof(Color));
var sysColors = GetConstants(typeof(SystemColors));

webColors.Sort(new StandardColorComparer());
sysColors.Sort(new SystemColorComparer());
```

with `StandardColorComparer` and `SystemColorComparer` defined as follows:

```
class StandardColorComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
    // Methods
    public int Compare(Color color, Color color2)
    {
        if (color.A < color2.A)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (color.A > color2.A)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (color.GetHue() < color2.GetHue())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (color.GetHue() > color2.GetHue())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (color.GetSaturation() < color2.GetSaturation())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (color.GetSaturation() > color2.GetSaturation())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (color.GetBrightness() < color2.GetBrightness())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (color.GetBrightness() > color2.GetBrightness())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

class SystemColorComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
    // Methods
    public int Compare(Color color, Color color2)
    {
        return string.Compare(color.Name, color2.Name, false, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

**N.B. :**

This code has been taken from `System.Drawing.Design.ColorEditor` through reflector.

Comment: Node: `GetConstants` is (basically) the same used in the color picker used for `BackgroundColor`, etc.. properties

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The fact is that both solutions return the colors sorted according to string name. I would like the colors sorted as in the Visual studio tab, where red-like colors are clustered ecc....

Comment: I tried this solution and now it works ok!

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Klaus78: I don't want appear too eager of points, but if you think this is a good answer, you should upvote it, and also if you think it's THE correct answer you should accept it... ;)

Comment: @digEmAll @Klaus Hey, What was wrong with my solution? ;-) Same result but with 1/10 the code

Comment: @Magnus: nothing wrong, in fact I upvoted it. Mine is exaclty the code used by VS designer to show colors, but results should be the same :)

Comment: GetConstants return type must List<Color> or IEnumerable<Color>

Answer (score 10):

```
var webColors = 
  Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
    .Cast<KnownColor>()
    .Where (k => k >= KnownColor.Transparent && k < KnownColor.ButtonFace) //Exclude system colors
    .Select(k => Color.FromKnownColor(k));
```

**EDIT:**

To order the colors append:

```
.OrderBy(c => c.GetHue())
.ThenBy(c => c.GetSaturation())
.ThenBy(c => c.GetBrightness());
```

Comment: Much more concise than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it sorted by its primary color you could use this as starting point:

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
                 .Cast<KnownColor>()
                 .Select(kc => Color.FromKnownColor(kc))
                 .OrderBy(c => c.GetHue())
```